# how to select value from database using hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am newbie for hibernate,i am using mysql database,with two tables serviceTypeDetails,validateConfig.In serviceTypeDetails,it's having four types of services and another table validateconfig contain 31 row with respect to each servicetypeid,using hibernate how i am able to select data from validateConfig and what are required mapping association and query for it.[image]

### ServiceTypeDetails.java

```
package com.example.HibernateDataManager;
public class ServiceTypeDetails
{
     private Long Id;
     private String serviceTypeName;
    public ServiceTypeDetails()
    {
    }
    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.Id=id;
    }
    public Long getId()
    {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setServiceTypeName(String serviceName)
    {
        this.serviceTypeName=serviceName;
    }
    public String getServiceTypeName()
    {
        return serviceTypeName;
    }
}
```

### ValidateConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.HibernateDataManager;

public class ValidateConfiguration
{
    private Long Id;
    private String fieldName;
    private String modeValue;

    public ValidateConfiguration()
    {

    }

    public void setId(Long serviceID)
    {
        this.Id=serviceID;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return Id;
    }


    public void setFieldName(String fieldName)
    {
        this.fieldName=fieldName;
    }

    public String getFieldName()
    {
        return fieldName;
    }


     public void setModeValue(String modevalue)
    {
        this.modeValue=modevalue;
    }

    public String getModeValue()
    {
        return modeValue;
    }

}
```

### Main.java

```
package com.arosys.HibernateDataManager;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String s[])
    { try{
        SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        String sql_query= "from  ValidateConfiguration";
        Query query=session.createQuery(sql_query);
        System.out.println(query);
        for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();)
        {
           ValidateConfiguration std = ( ValidateConfiguration) it.next();
          System.out.println("serviceTypeID: " + std.getId());
          System.out.println("FieldName: " + std.getFieldName());
        // System.out.println("ModeValue: " + validateconfig.getModeValue());
       }

        session.close();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
 }
```

Comment: show us some of your attempts?

Comment: Do you have the backing POJO classes, without the objects there is no point in ORM, you might as well use plain SQL.

Comment: I agree with Manoj. Revert back to plain SQL.

Comment: when i try to execute a query throws Exception: More than one row with the given identifier was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
```

in your hibernate.cfg.xml.

Then check what SQL query is getting generated.

The problem more seems towards Database Design.